# Error: Cannot find module 'stream/web' when running 'npm start' for Next.js app despite correct Node version

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I tried to install a next application by running `npm create next-app --typescript`. After installation, when I ran `npm start`, I got an error msg saying "Error: Cannot find module 'stream/web'": here's a snippet of the procedure:

```
(base) ➜  Next-Project npm create next-app --typescript
Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y
✔ What is your project named? … my-app
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias? … No / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app 


Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@13.4.19',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16.8.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.24.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 23 packages, and audited 24 packages in 3s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created my-app at /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app

(base) ➜  Next-Project ls
my-app
(base) ➜  Next-Project cd my-app 
(base) ➜  my-app git:(main) npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> next start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'stream/web'
Require stack:
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-web-streams.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/index.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-web-streams.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-web-streams.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/index.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js',
    '/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/Next-Project/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
  ]
}
```

One think I've noticed was that the next-app installation information indicated my current node version is 'v15.14.0' `by saying npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.24.2' }` However when I run `nvm ls` and `node --version`, both show that my node version is v18.17.1:

```
(base) ➜  Next-Project nvm ls
        v18.2.0
->     v18.17.1
         system
default -> node (-> v18.17.1)
node -> stable (-> v18.17.1) (default)
stable -> 18.17 (-> v18.17.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.17.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.17.1
(base) ➜  Next-Project node --version
npm --version
v18.17.1
10.0.0
```

Do you know what caused the issue? Thanks in advance.

I've tried upgrading and downgrading the node version and the npm version, trying to make them compatibly match each other. And after each attempt, I would remove and reinstall node_modules and package-lock.json files before launching the app. I think the problem might be the version incompatibility.

Answer (score 7):

I checked and it seems that next requires a node engine with a version >= 16.4.
Try to upgrade your node version. Regards

---- // ----

I did myself and indeed it solve the issue:

[/w version 16.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdj6.png)

[/w version >18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy4QC.png)

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I managed to resolve this issue by deleting the package.json file that I had inadvertently installed in a higher-level directory (at the root directory ~) a while back. Nonetheless, I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same with next.js and electron app. I did this and it works for me.

```bash
npm install electron@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by deleting the package.json file that I had inadvertently installed in a higher-level directory (at the root directory ~) a while back.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case thie error occurred after installing

```
npm i socket-client-io
```

packege where node version of my project was not compatible with that lastest version of socet-client-io.

SO, I reduced the  version of socket-client-io from version 6 to 4.5.4

```
npm i socket.io-client@4.5.4
```